# How to identify the MKMapItem from MKLocalSearchCompletion object in iOS9.3?

Tags: ios, ios9.3, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

Apple introduced the MKLocalSearchCompleter and MKLocalSearchCompletion in iOS 9.3. I am trying to implement it. It becomes a two step process 
1) enter partial term -> full search text is generated.
2) User selects one of these to search for the actual location.

The question is if I search for 200 townsend, it gives me a list of locations but it is till treated as suggestion by the app. 
How can we identify if it is a MKMampItem or suggestion?

Answer (score 12):

One way to do this is to initialize a `MKLocalSearchRequest` with a `MKLocalSearchCompletion`.

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest(completion: completion)
```

You can then initialize a `MKLocalSearch` with a `MKLocalSearchRequest`.

```
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
```

You can then start the `search` which has a completion handler with a `MKLocalSearchResponse?` and `NSError?`.  The `MKLocalSearchResponse?` will have an array of `MKMapItem`'s.

Full example:

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest(completion: completion)
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response: MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) in
    if let error = error {
        // do something with "error"
    }
    else if let mapItems = response?.mapItems {
        // do something with "mapItems"
    }
}
```

Comment: Download the Apple Official Sample Code here that explains how to make the `MKLocalSearchRequest` from from an `MKLocalSearchCompletion`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/searching_for_nearby_points_of_interest

Comment: Does this risk getting rate limited? I have experience some problems when making many calls in debug